# How to set location persmission granted from custom dialog using flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, location, android-permissions, customdialog

I want to set the location permission using a custom dialog and not the built native dialoges.
If user press 'agree' then permission should be granted if presses 'disagree' then premssion should be denied

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, **you can't.**
As android documentation puts:
[You can find more detailed information here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Android only.

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Thank you for the reply.